# Sending private message on Facebook with android sdk 3.15,0

Tags: android, facebook

I have been using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog and i am using the below code to send private messages through facebook sdk 3.15.0.

Facebook login has been working correctly and Session has been passed correctly to the activity.

If anyone can offer any advice on permissions that allow a user to send private messages over Facebook that might help, so far I cannot find any more permissions to help me.

```
       Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
            .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "user_friends"));
    activeFacebookSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(MapDisplay.this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/")
            .setName("USER FLAG")
            .setCaption("USER_NAME has invited you to EST_NAME!")
            .setPicture("http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png")
            .setDescription("Allow your users to message links from your app using the Android SDK.")
            .setDataErrorsFatal(true)
            .setFragment(facebookMessageController);
```

**Error**
It sends succesfully from android perspective and returns to the activity correctly. When I check my messages it looks like it sent okay, however the person receiving the message gets an error, linked below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO6xU.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hi Phillium, Any luck working with FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder ?

Comment: Sorry to say I've not made any progress with this so I've been working on other things.